# Spilting Complex String hy Complex String

Tags: c#, string, web-scraping, split

I'm developing a desktop base search scraper, I need to split complex page source according checks. I'm not able to split it. Anyone may help

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb web = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb();
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = web.Load("http://www.google.com/search?q=" + tb_text.Text);
    String[] values;
    String data = doc.Text;   
    // case1 : Left Block
    String Case1 = "\"mraOPb\"><span>" + tb_text.Text;
    if (data.Any((Case1).Contains))
    { 
     Console.WriteLine("Check true");
     values = data.Split(new string[] {Case1}, StringSplitOptions.None);
      result_label.Text = values[1]; // Out of Index Exception
     }
```

I've used check confirm checking for debugging and its true.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
if (data.Any((Case1).Contains))
```

is true if any of the characters in `Case1` appear anywhere in `data`. To find if the whole string `Case1` is present in `data`, you can write:

```
if (data.Contains(Case1))
```